# How to extract with regex an optional 2nd capturing group after arbitrary string following the first mandatory capturing group

Tags: python, regex

In a Pandas dataframe I have a column with string descriptions that needs to be parsed to several attributes and I'm trying to do that with `str.extract` method.
Since description may contain several attributes - set of mandatory and one optional - I'm trying to use two capturing groups with arbitrary string in between.
As an example I can show the following string:

```
xx gjkdnfXYX 100E sadhb-saj D123 sjn
```

where **XYX** is start of the template description, **100E** corresponds to the set of  mandatory capturing groups and **D123** is an optional group (letter D and 2 or 3 digits after).
With the regex:

```
(?<=XYX)[\s]*(\d{1,2})(\d)[\s]*([A-Z])?.*(D\d{2,3})
```

I'm able to extract both groups, but it will completely fail if 2nd one will be absent.
In case I will add `?` after the 2nd group - it won't be captured, probably due to greedy `.*` quantifier. But if I make it lazy with `?` after - it will match only one character then.

I will be grateful for your advises since I'm already lack of ideas...
And here is the link to play around the above example:
https://regex101.com/r/rTO4kl/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern making the last part `.*(D\d{2,3})` optional:

```
(?<=XYX)\s*(\d{1,2})(\d)\s*([A-Z])?(?:.*(D\d{2,3}))?
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RHLbGm/1).